# Routing from via remote bridge

Tags: networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, udp

Below is a diagram of my server and laptop, both inside the same LAN.

On the left, I have a server with a bridge ip (.128). The server also allocate another ip (.118) from the router but only accessible via the bridge or internally (eg I can't ping .118 from anywhere else in the lan). The .118 internal ip listen to UDP port.

I need to tell my laptop (.107) to send all udp to .118 via .128 and get the answer back.

Image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9C30.png

Both side are using Ubuntu. the server is Ubuntu 18 and my laptop is v20.

Thanks

Yoram

Comment: I've turned on forwarding on both machine.
On the laptop I added: `sudo ip route add 192.168.1.118/32 via 192.168.1.128`. I now see the call on the server with tcpdump but it stills not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: actually my mistake, sudo ip route add 192.168.1.118/32 via 192.168.1.128 works, sorry guys, I'm new here. My problem was that I was sending dtls v1.0 and Ubuntu 20 does not allow it. When this happen here, do you delete the question?

Comment: No no, you answer your own question with the solution that worked for you! Message me when you do.